# Setting a navigators key gives void error

Tags: flutter

How can i set a navigators key from a provider? I tried `key: Provider.of<RoutesProvider>(context).setHomeKey()`, but I get an error saying:

> This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.

Here's my code:

```dart
class RoutesProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  GlobalKey _homeKey = GlobalKey();

  get homeKey => _homeKey;


  void setHomeKey(GlobalKey newKey) {
    _homeKey = newKey;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Navigator(
      key: Provider.of<RoutesProvider>(context).setHomeKey()
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (context) {
            switch (settings.name) {
              case '/':
                return Home();
              default:
                throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
            }
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

The new error I'm, getting when pushing to a new route:

```
Exception: Invalid route: /someRouteInHome

The relevant error-causing widget was
    Navigator-[GlobalKey#88e11]
```

Comment: YOU ARE TRYING TO GET KEY FROM  VOID FUNC ? I THINK YOU SHOULD USE : Provider.of<RoutesProvider>(context).homeKey

Comment: @DeepakRor Thanks, that works, but now when I try rerouting using that global key it's giving an error: `final BuildContext homeContext = Provider.of<RoutesProvider>(context, listen: false).homeKey.currentContext; Navigator.of(homeContext).pushNamed('/someRouteInHome');`

Comment: can you add your error in your question

Comment: @DeepakRor added